What electronic component is this in my electronic device?
What electronic component is this in my electronic device?


It might be a diode or maybe a thermistor. It would help if we knew what equipment it was from and a more general picture of the circuit so we have more context.

@Kartman Is another possibility a Ceramic Axial Capacitor? See KYOCERA AVX SA305E105MAR for an example, albeit haven't found anything with the same colour scheme. Agree that a more general picture of the circuit would help, including if there is any adjacent reference designator on the silk screen, which might identify the type of component.

I have found it. This is a Soviet Diode КД209Б silicon, diffusion, rectifier.

That is almost certainly a diode.  Given the fatness of the leads, probably a 1 A rectifier.  Back in the 60's and 70's, a US surplus dealer called Poly-Paks was big on these.
A larger image with more of the surrounding components for context would help.

A comment on the question says This is a Soviet Diode КД209Б silicon. From a search found https://www-kontest-ru.translate.goog/catalog/item/6549200?_x_tr_sl=ru&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=sc for which the google translation from Russian to English says KD209B Silicon diode 400V, 0.7A

@ChesterGillon https://eandc.ru/pdf/diod/kd209.pdf says 0.5A.
